# Access ActiveMQ queues with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, asp.net-core, activemq-classic, .net-core

I have a question regarding RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ.
Different departments are using ActiveMQ in my company.
They use it for JMS Queuing.

Next week, I want to start a new project with .NET Core 1.0 RTM which have to access this JMS queues by the end of this year.
At the moment RabbitMQ seems to be the only project which support .NET Core.

So, my question is, is it possible to read and write in ActiveMQ queues with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily bridge brokers using [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).  Camel has components for both [RabbitMQ](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) and [ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) that would allow you to define a route that bridges the destinations you want to share messages with.  The Camel site has plenty of docs to get you started.